# pandas.read_sql and Oracle sql developer output different results

Tags: sql, pandas, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running same query via pd.read_sql and Oracle SQLDeveloper and get slightly different outputs. As a result database migration testing missed incorrect precision/scale in target tables.

```
pd.read_sql(f"select sum({col}) from {schema}.{table}",ora_conn)
```

the outputs below are from querying through pandas and SQLDeveloper respectively:
34840319411.5366**89**75830078
34840319411.5366**90**2148639954454213285388

Given the difference appears in the middle it does not look like a rounding issue. So I am very keen to know what causes this and what can be done to address this?

UPD: not sure if it matters, but pandas and sql developer use different versions of Oracle client

Comment: What is the data type of `col`?

Comment: @JustinCave datat ype is NUMBER

Comment: What are the precision and scale on the number column?

Comment: @JustinCave precision = 46, scale = 38

Comment: How are you determining the precision and scale?  You can't define a column as `number(46,38)`.  What does `user_tab_columns` show for `data_precision` and `data_scale`?

Comment: @JustinCave, `user_tab_columns` has `null` for precision and scale for 99% of NUMBER columns. Not sure why. The longest number in the column has a length of 39. To define precision and scale I determine max number of characters to the right from a decimal point and to the left (dot and minus are not counted). The former I treat as scale and the sum of two as precision. I use this logic as I need to migrate the data into SQL Server and need to define a column.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be the read_sql function is defaulted to convert values of non-string, non-numeric objects (like decimal.Decimal) to floating point. You can turn it off by using `coerce_float=False`.

```
pd.read_sql(f"select sum({col}) from {schema}.{table}",ora_conn, coerce_float = False)
```

Comment: coerce_float=False does not change anything in this case.